# Returning all together instead of 1-by-1

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

There's multiple `Content-child`.
But the result returning it 1-by-1.

```
element1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='Content']")
element2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='Content-child']")

for element3 in element2:
    element3_list = element3.text

    df = pd.DataFrame(element3_list, columns=['a','b','c'])
    pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
    print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

----RESULT----

```
+--+----+----+----+
|   | a  | b  | c  |
+---|----+----+----+
| 0 | 3  | 1  | 21 |
+---+----+----+----+

+--+----+----+----+
|   | a  | b  | c  |
+---|----+----+----+
| 0 | 5  | 8  | 41 |
+---+----+----+----+
```

What I expected was

```
+--+----+----+----+
|   | a  | b  | c  |
+---|----+----+----+
| 0 | 3  | 1  | 21 |
+---+----+----+----+
| 1 | 5  | 8  | 41 |
+---+----+----+----+
```

Is it loop mistake or is there any module that can combine it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let us restore your `df` into a `list` within the for loop

```
l=[]
for element3 in element2:
    element3_list = element3.text

    l.append(pd.DataFrame(element3_list, columns=['a','b','c']))

df=pd.concat(l).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You creare new data frame in each step of `for element3 in element2` loop. Then you print such created data frame.

What you should do instead is to create one (perhaps empty) DataFrame **before** loop, then for each `element3` append row to existing data frame using [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) method, and finaly print result **after** leaving loop.

BTW take a look at example at the end of mentioned link using `pd.concat` method. This one should be perfect for your needs.

Comment: Thank you. Just the problem with loop.